# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in tableview application

Tags: iphone, root, tableview, exc-bad-access

This is my first iPhone application and it's based on a top-level tableview. Selections of rows either go to another tableview or to a view. The application runs OK on the simulator but when ported to my iPhone it fails with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. This happens while my splash screen is being displayed. NSLog indicates that the program processes in appDelegate.m:

```
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

but then it just fails. The code never seems to reach the viewDidLoad in my RootViewController.

I'm sure that I've got the RootViewController and appDelegates mixed up somehow but cannot figure out exactly what's wrong. I've attached the beginning code of my RootViewController, appDelegate - any help appreciated.

RootViewController.h code....

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
TyresViewController *tyresController;
EngineSpecViewController *engineSpecController;
CarbonTaxBandViewController *carbonTaxBandController;
TyreSpecificationsViewController *tyreSpecificationsController;
FuelConsumptionandEmissionsViewController *fuelConsumptionandEmissionsController;
CompanyCarTaxBandViewController *companyCarTaxBandController;
CarbonCalculatorViewController *carbonCalculatorController;
ReminderViewController *reminderController;

//NSString *selectedSpecification;  
NSArray *listOfItems;
```

}

RootViewController.m code ......

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize listOfItems;
//@synthesize selectedSpecification;
@synthesize carbonTaxBandController;
@synthesize engineSpecController;
@synthesize tyreSpecificationsController;
@synthesize tyresController;
@synthesize fuelConsumptionandEmissionsController;
@synthesize companyCarTaxBandController;
@synthesize carbonCalculatorController;
@synthesize reminderController;
```

appDelegate.h code.....

```
@interface MyCar3AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

UIWindow *window;
UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

}

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

@end

appDelegate.m code .....

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

// Override point for customization after app launch    

[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought, in your main Info.plist file there should be an entry for `Main nib file base name`. This refers to the nib that will be loaded when your app starts. The simulator is not case sensitive, but the device is. Check the case of the value of your main nib.